# how to compare two 1d arrays and output the indices where array 1 has the same scalar value as array 2

Tags: arrays, matlab, comparison

I'm trying to figure out how to take two 1d arrays, put it in a function so that every number in array 1 is compared to every number in array 2, and then the element numbers of the duplicate numbers found is displayed with respect to array 1

for example
array 1 = [12,16,36,72,82]
array 2= [16,53,72,12,40,71]

and the output would be
elements= 1 2 4

I'm new to Matlab so I don't currently have all the skills to make This work I'm trying to figure it out but I don't know what exactly to do.
it won't let me post the code because it doesn't make sense.
im not sure how to post is on her otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit2]

**Best approach**

The unreliable approach below works for the example given by the OP, with the restriction discussed below. The best approach is using MATLAB's `ismember` and `find` functions:

```
array1 = [12,16,36,72,82]; 
array2 = [16,53,72,12,40,71];

idc = find( ismember(array1, array2 ) )
```

- `ismember(array1, array2)` returns a logical array indicating which elements of `array1` are contained in `array2`.
- `find(...)` converts the logical array to indices.

[Edit1]

**Alternative approach**

An approach without `ismember` would be:

```
array1 = [12,16,36,72,82]; 
array2 = [16,53,72,12,40,71];

findFcn = @(X) find( array1(:) == X )';
idcs = arrayfun(findFcn, array2(:), 'UniformOutput', false );
idcs = unique([idcs{:}])
```

Explanation:

- `findFun(X)` gives the index of the value of `X` in `array1`.
- `findFun(X)` is called by `arrayfun` with `X` being equal to each element of `array2` and `arrayfun` stores the return values of the calls to the cell array idcs.
- Finally, `idcs = unique([idcs{:}]);` converts the cell array `idc` to a double array and removes repetitions.

[First answer]

**Unreliable approach**

You can use the `intersect` function:

```
array1 = [12,16,36,72,82]; 
array2 = [16,53,72,12,40,71];
[ ~, x1 ] =  intersect( array1, array2 );
```

`~` means that the first return value, which would be the intersection of `array1` and `array2`, is discarded. `x1` is then equal to the indices that the intersection's values have in `array1`.

If you also want to have the indices in `array2` you could do

```
[ ~, x1, x2 ] =  intersect( array1, array2 );
```

to store them in `x2`.

*Note:*
`x1` and  `x2` only contain the indices of the first occurrence in `array1` and `array2`, respectively.

Comment: I tried to do this with two 1d arrays of different sizes and it didn't work? any idea why?

Comment: The arrays in my answer have also different sizes and it works, so that is not the problem.